# Как избавиться от повторного поиска максимума в таблице?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть кусок SQL запроса, где мне нужно пройтись по таблице и найти самый большой id среди записей, соответствующих некоторому критерию. Но, если ни одной записи, подходящей под критерий отбора ещё нет, нужно просто вернуть 1.
Написал вот такой скрипт:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN (SELECT max(table.id)
          FROM table
          WHERE table.title = 'bar') IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE
         (SELECT max(table.id)
          FROM table
          WHERE table.title = 'bar')
    END
```

Хочу избавиться от дублирования поиска максимального `id`. В обычном коде я бы ввёл переменную, однако всё, что пробовал для SQL, выдавало синтаксические ошибки. Уверен, что есть очень простое решение, которое я не могу найти.

Comment: `SELECT COALESCE((SELECT max(table.id) FROM table WHERE table.title = 'bar'), 1)`

Comment: А ещё есть CTE.

Comment: Спасибо, `COALESCE` оказалось как раз тем, что нужно. Если сделаете ответом, отмечу, как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE( ( SELECT max(table.id) 
                   FROM table 
                   WHERE table.title = 'bar'), 1)
```